# sed not working from sh file, but working from the command line

Tags: sed

`sed` works from the command line, but does not work if put it in an `sh` file and execute it.  I want to change a number in an existing file and direct it to a new file, so I tried this:

```
echo enter number 
read num
var1='more ods2.sql | egrep -e "test" | cut -c 5-7' 
sed "s/test$var1/test$num/g" ods2.sql > odstest.sql
```

If I execute these statements in a prompt they execute with the desired results. I replaced `$var1` with the string I passed, e.g `12345`:

```
sed "s/test$var1/test$num/g" ods2.sql > odstest.sql
```

This also works fine from a prompt:

```
more ods2.sql | egrep -e "test" | cut -c 5-7'
```

Why isn't it working if I put this in a shell script?

Answer (score 7):

This line

```
var1='more ods2.sql | egrep -e "test" | cut -c 5-7'
```

should be

```
var1=`more ods2.sql | egrep -e "test" | cut -c 5-7`
```

i.e. you need to use backticks instead of single quotes (apostrophes).

Comment: or use `$()` which is easier to see, [among other benefits](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Comment: I'm not sure what `more` is supposed to be accomplishing either. Its probably best to remove it and have egrep read the file directly, or at the very least use `cat` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`more` is intended to work in a terminal. A simpler way is

```
var1=$(< ods2.sql grep "test" | cut -c 5-7)
sed "s/test$var1/test$num/g" ods2.sql > odstest.sql
```

Nit pick: be careful about that first line, though. You're making assumptions about the position and length of the text you want to extract from ods2.sql. I don't know what is `var1` supposed to look like, but here's an example assuming it's a number:

```
var1=$(< ods2.sql sed -n 's/test\([:digit:]*\)/\1/p')
if ! [ -n "$var1" ]  # sed didn't find the pattern
    # complain, exit
fi
```